# In Dart with Pub, when should I use the "any" version constraint for a dependency?

Tags: versioning, dart, dart-pub, semantic-versioning

When making a package, I am often confused as to whether I should use the `any` constraint.

I know that for:

- **library packages**, [I should specify clear version constraints](http://pub.dartlang.org/doc/glossary.html#library-package) so that users of my libraries know the version of my transitive dependencies,
- **application packages**, [I should use `any` and check in my `pubspec.lock` lockfile](http://pub.dartlang.org/doc/glossary.html#application-package) so that others can run my application,

but there is a grey area for:

- **applications that are meant to be extended**, such as codelabs, tutorials, templates, examples, and others.
- **applications that also have re-usable libraries**; that is, packages that have a `lib` directory for common functionality that doesn't make sense to put in a separate package, but also a `web` directory for a full-fledged application.

---

**Question:** When exactly should I use  the `any` version constraint, and when should I fully specify the version constraint for Pub packages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **applications that are meant to be extended**, such as codelabs, tutorials, templates, examples, and others.

Since these are often going to be copy-pasted as the basis of normal application packages, I'd use the `any` constraint and check in a lockfile to set a good example.

> **applications that also have re-usable libraries**; that is, packages that have a `lib` directory for common functionality that doesn't make sense to put in a separate package, but also a `web` directory for a full-fledged application.

All applications should put their code in the `lib` directory. The `web` directory should just contain the entrypoint(s). So this is just a standard application package, which should use the `any` constraint and check in a lockfile.